Are song titles subject to trademark?
Does this mean that several different songs from different artists can share the same name?

It's trivially easy with a minimal amount of searching to establish that a number of songs do share their names with totally different songs written by different people.  Likely titles are those with one word, such as "Yesterday"; the Wikipedia disambiguation page lists 19 such songs if I counted correctly, not including those called "Yesterdays."  Are you asking whether anyone has ever taken anyone else to court over something like this?

@phoog FWIW: "X has happened before" is not a particularly helpful observation when trying to determine whether X is legal. The vast majority of laws exist precisely because the proscribed behavior has happened before.

@bdb484 it's not only whether it happens but what the legal consequences are.  That's why I asked if the question is about court cases arising from songs sharing a title, since the answer to the literal question, "can they share the same title," is trivially yes.  Another relevant fact is that companies that public music and release recordings of music typically have intellectual property lawyers on staff, so if it weren't legal the lawyers would force a change in the song's name before it made it to the Wikipedia list.

@phoog I think that's an unreasonably blinkered way of looking at the question. If someone is coming to law.SE rather than MetaphysicalPossibilities.SE, I think it's safe for us to assume that when they ask whether one "can" or "cannot" do something, they are asking whether the law permits or forbids it, rather than asking whether it is humanly possible to do something in the absence of wizarding abilities.

@bdb484 if I had thought it was a comprehensive answer to the question, I would have posted it as an answer.  Stack Exchange questions are generally supposed to show basic research effort.  The question shows no awareness of the fact that song titles are widely shared.  But to your point, the fact that songs share titles is not at all comparable to the fact that (for example) people steal.  The publication of a song is by definition a public act, whereas theft is typically a covert act. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the context in which it's done matters, as does the reaction.


[Can] several different songs from different artists can share the
same name?

Yes. There are many examples of this. See, e.g., "Yesterday" (via a comment by phoog), which is the title of 19 independent songs. A quick Google search found a list of 172 song titles used by more tha one song.
Song titles are generally also too short or generic or descriptive to be subject to copyright protections.
The most common situation where a song title becomes a trademark or service mark as well as just a song title is when the band that records the song has the same name as its "trademark song". And, even then, the trademark/service mark that arises is usually is in the market place of music bands and not in the marketplace of songs.

Are song titles subject to trademark?

Song titles aren't categorically immune from trademark or service mark liability. But the mere fact that someone has a song with a particular title doesn't make it automatically protected by trademark laws either. Indeed, usually a song title won't give rise to a trademark. It is rare for a song title to acquire a "secondary meaning" which is a key part of a trademark.
Addison Rae's song "Diet Pepsi", for example, is a trademark, but it is being used in a way that does not suggest that it has the authorization or endorsement of PepsiCo, it isn't being used to market a good or service, and isn't being used in the Xerox sense as a generic noun that dilutes the trademark. So, it is probably not an infringing use (and the title may have even been used with permission, given the belts and suspenders tendencies of music industry intellectual property lawyers).
It would be rare for a song title to infringe a trademark, and even more rare for a song title that is the same as another song's title constitute trademark infringement.

Kodak apparently insisted that Paul Simon include the trademark symbol for Kodachrome.
